# iTextSharp throw exception OutOfMemoryException with Larg file

Tags: pdf-generation, itext, out-of-memory

I'm using iTextSharp (5.4.1.0) to merge set of PDF files into one file.
In case of having larg file i got System.OutOfMemoryException at the line of closing document [document.Close();]

Here is my merging function:

```
    public static byte[] MergeFiles(List<string> sourceFiles)
    {
        Document document = new Document();
        MemoryStream output = new MemoryStream();

        // Initialize pdf writer
        PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, output);
        writer.PageEvent = new PdfPageEvents();

        try
        {
            // Open document to write
            document.Open();
            PdfContentByte content = writer.DirectContent;

            PdfReader reader;
            PdfImportedPage importedPage;

            // Iterate through all pdf documents
            for (int fileCounter = 0; fileCounter < sourceFiles.Count; fileCounter++)
            {

                Console.WriteLine("File(" + (fileCounter + 1).ToString() + ") : " + sourceFiles[fileCounter].ToString());


                // Create pdf reader
                reader = new PdfReader(new iTextSharp.text.pdf.RandomAccessFileOrArray(sourceFiles[fileCounter]), null);
                //reader = new PdfReader(sourceFiles[fileCounter]);
                int numberOfPages = reader.NumberOfPages;

                // Iterate through all pages
                for (int currentPageIndex = 1; currentPageIndex <= numberOfPages; currentPageIndex++)
                {
                    // Determine page size for the current page
                    document.SetPageSize(reader.GetPageSizeWithRotation(currentPageIndex));
                    // Create page
                    document.NewPage();
                    importedPage = writer.GetImportedPage(reader, currentPageIndex);
                    // Determine page orientation
                    int pageOrientation = reader.GetPageRotation(currentPageIndex);
                    if ((pageOrientation == 90) || (pageOrientation == 270))
                    {
                        content.AddTemplate(importedPage, 0, -1f, 1f, 0, 0, reader.GetPageSizeWithRotation(currentPageIndex).Height);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        content.AddTemplate(importedPage, 1f, 0, 0, 1f, 0, 0);
                    }
                }


            }

            document.Close();
            writer.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ErrorsHandling.LogException("MergeFiles", ex.Message, ex.StackTrace);
        }

        return output.GetBuffer();
    }
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You use a memory stream as output of your merge; thus, in the course of `document.close`and `writer.close` the whole result PDF is present in memory. Have to tried merging into a file stream instead? BTW: Using a `PdfWriter` for merging documents generally is not a good idea. Using some `Pdf*Copy*` class usually is the better approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bug here was that i'm returning "output.GetBuffer();" and after that don't freeing MemoryStream.